# Aside paths, what are the other kinds of persistent file references on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, file

When I open a text document in TextEdit, quit it, rename the file and relaunch TextEdit, the renamed file will automatically be opened. The same holds true if the file is moved to a different folder.

I'm concluding from this experiment that whatever handles what documents should be automatically reopened on Mac OS X doesn't use file paths, or at least doesn't only use file paths.

So, aside from file paths, what kind of file reference I can write to a document that will remain valid even if the target file is renamed or moved while my app is not running?

I'm interested in this because I'm working on an app that might need to store references to other files inside its own documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `NSURL` based solutions. You can create a bookmark, which will refer to the file even after it's been moved / renamed.

Borrowing from [FileWatcher on GitHub by Peter Sugihara](https://github.com/ptrsghr/FileWatcher/blob/master/FileWatcherExample/Classes/FileWatcher.m):

```
- (NSData *)bookmarkFromURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSData *bookmark = [url bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationPreferFileIDResolution
                     includingResourceValuesForKeys:NULL
                                      relativeToURL:NULL
                                              error:NULL];
    return bookmark;
}

- (NSURL *)urlFromBookmark:(NSData *)bookmark {
    NSError *error = noErr;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmark
                                           options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutUI
                                     relativeToURL:NULL
                               bookmarkDataIsStale:NULL
                                             error:&error];
    if (error != noErr)
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    return url;
}
```

You can safely persist the returned bookmark data, and it will point to the same file after your app has been relaunched.

Additional info in official documentation: [Locating Files Using Bookmarks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW10)

**EDIT:** As per very valid suggestions by Peter Hosey related to error handling in the above code, a note: the above code from FileWatcher does not handle errors according to standards, and is attached to serve as a guideline.

Please refer to the official documentation for details.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with the error-handling in that code: ◆ The first method does not accept an error object from `bookmarkDataWithOptions::::`, even though the method can fail. (The documentation lists at least some of the failure cases.) ◆ The latter method initializes `error` to `noErr`, which is an `OSStatus` (old Mac OS error number) value, rather than `nil`. ◆ Similarly, it then compares it to `noErr`. ◆ It redundantly sends `description` to the error, then passes that to `NSLog` for `%@`, which sends `description` anyway. ◆ It uses `NSLog` instead of presenting the error.

Comment: True, added a disclaimer note.

Comment: I get an error like this: `CFURLSetTemporaryResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed this URL which has no scheme`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Apollo Try with an absolute path NSURL, only thing that comes to mind with this kind of error.